# azure devops repos URL

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

I face an issue with Azure repos URL suddenly :

I have just started on a new project that was created in DevOps and the url it wants me to use is

https://OrgName@dev.azure.com/OrgName/RepoName/_git/RepoName

And that always fails (asks for credentials in a loop), this is the same if i click the Clone in VS Code.

However in my org that was created with devops years ago the GIT urls it gives me are like.

https://dev.azure.com/Test/_git/Test

If i remove the OrgName@ from the devops url it clones the repo fine, so why does devops add it and how can we either make it work with it in the url or stop devops providing it in the URL for a git repo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the reply of the Product Group in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1058997/view.html):

> This cannot be fixed at this time due to backwards compatibility with
> some old versions of Git Credential Manager. We plan to drop the org
> prefix in the short future, once we confirm it won’t impact a large
> base of users. Please understand that this is a priority for us,
> although it cannot be taking at this time yet.

Our product group has paid attention to this issue and has planned to **remove** the organization@ prefix in the future.

**Workaround:**

Method 1. As you said, you could manually delete the `organization@` in the git clone URL.

Method 2. You could disable the new URL in the Organizaiton Settings -> Overview

[image]

Then you could sign in the organizaiton with the old URL `organizationname.visualstuido.com` .

In this case, the git clone url will not contain the `organization@`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the “Clone” link in the top-right.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio):

> [image]

That should provide you with a proper link you can use.

Comment: Hi, yes. I used the link mentioned by you. by recently it has been changed from : https://https://dev.azure.com/Test/_git/Test to the new address : https://username@dev.azure.com/Test/_git/Test . so during the cloning, I have to clear the username from URL manually ,